# NetBeans not showing versioning changes in source editor

Tags: git, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 with git. Somehow NetBeans is not displaying the change indictions ([see here for what I mean](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#viewChanges)) when I change fieles in a git managed repository. Where can I enable this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, `Tools > Plugins > Installed` and make sure Git is there. If not, you can install it from the NetBeans catalog.

Then, `Tools > options > Misc > Versioning` and make sure Git is there.

Worked for me in 7.1.2.

For the formatting, go to `View > Show diff sidebar`

Comment: Git is working fine, the only thing missing are the line change indicators in the source editor as shown in the link.

Comment: What was far to easy! I was looking in the preference like crazy but somehow it never occurred to me to look in the menus. -.- Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just started using Git and had the same problem, but the above didn't fix it. Turns out changes are not highlighted until you have done your first commit (seems obvious now I know but was not at the time)